# Adding a popup context menu to words in a Flex TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, controls, user-interface

I'm trying to figure out how to add a popup context menu to words/groups of words in a flex.  Basically I'm trying to achieve something similar to the red underline MS Word adds underneath misspelled words.

I'd also like to be able to add controls other than menu items to this context menu (checkboxes, lists, buttons, etc...).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the ContextMenu class doesn't allow you to include anything but text (for links). You could always just create your own pseudo-context menu (Canvas + with whatever other components) and display it using the PopUpManager. I'm not sure if you can listen for RIGHT_CLICK events in flex (may only be AIR).